# How to get System out console from a jar loaded by a class loader?

Tags: java, system.out

I am running an external jar plugin like this:

```
  Class<?> pluginClass = pluginLoader.loadClass(".......");     
  Method main = pluginClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
  main.invoke(null, new Object[] { new String[0] });
```

It works great. Now need to save the plugin console messages into a String

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos); // how to indicate System.out coming from JAR plugin 
  System.setOut(ps); 
 // how to connect ps with plugin only
```

But this code saves ALL console messages into String. I don't need all application messages. How to redirect **plugin only** messages......messages coming from this loaded jar into the string?

Comment: System out is a very thin wrapper for the much older [**standard output stream**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and that has a file descriptor of **1**. There are no "plugin only" messages to standard output, because it's a *global*. Modify your plugin to write to a configurable logger.

Comment: thank you. i cannot modify plugin source code. this plugin is a jar that has `System.out.println` . i want to capture those messages

Comment: You cannot I'm afraid. Find a better written plugin? Anything that uses `System.out` and is not a tutorial or learning example should be given a very wide berth. Following the same line of questioning - why are _you_ using `System.out`?

Comment: Modify your own code to write to a configurable logger, and then the only thing writing to stdout will be the plugin and your posted code works great for getting that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this workaround:

```
public class CustomPrintStream extends PrintStream {
    private String prefix;

    public CustomPrintStream(String prefix, OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String s) {
        if(s.startsWith(prefix))
            super.println(s);
        else {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
            System.out.println(s);
            System.setOut(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This offers you the possibility to add a prefix to each of you main program's System.out.printlns, so that they get executed normally. The ones without the prefix (from your plugin) get directly into the defined out-stream (in my example the fileoutputstream)

It is used like this:

```
System.setOut(new CustomPrintStream("test", new FileOutputStream("C:\\out.txt"))); //Of course you can also use ByteArrayOutputStream, as you did before
System.out.println("test 1"); //this goes into the standard outstream
System.out.println("2"); //and this goes into the fileoutputstream
System.out.println("test 3");
```

Maybe this will help you :)

**Edit:** I switched it around so that the string with prefix goes into the normal outstream

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you are asking.  There is only one standard output stream in the process and it is shared with the plugin code and your code.

You could instead run the plugin code as a separate process and capture the output stream.  You can use the "java.home" System Property to find the location of the JRE that launched your process and use that to form a command line to launch the plugin jar.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: You mean: run in the plugin in a different JVM? How would it be a "plugin" then, plugging into the real application, that runs in the parent JVM?

Comment: @GhostCat Right. It's a plugin to your application that runs in a separate process, but is still controlled by your application.  Many programs work this way. It is heavier, but the process isolation offers other advantages as well. Many web browsers these days use a different process per page. Don't be too concerned that the plugin isn't running in the same process.  That may matter for performance, but only be concerned if that is a real problem.

Comment: run plugin inside a ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @john Use ProcessBuilder to launch the new process that runs your plugin jar.  There is no "inside" of a ProcessBuilder.  It is not a container.

Answer (score 3):

System.out is per process, no way to have different stream per class loader. If you desperately need to get the system out from plugin there are 2 options :
1. Pass output stream to your plugin if you have acces to its code and make plugin use this stream. 
2. Run your plugin as external process. This way you will be able to redirect its output.
Another option : if you can differentiate the plugins output, you can implement your own routing output stream and set it as system out.